# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан целочисленный массив из 30 элементов. Элементы массива могут принимать натуральные значения от 1 до 10 000 включительно. Опишите на одном из языков программирования алгоритм, который находит минимум среди элементов массива, не делящихся нацело на 6, а затем заменяет каждый элемент, не делящийся нацело на 6, на число, равное
найденному минимуму. Гарантируется, что хотя бы один такой элемент в массиве есть. В качестве результата необходимо вывести изменённый массив, каждый элемент выводится с новой строчки. Например, для исходного массива из шести элементов:

```
14
6
11
18
9
24
```

программа должна вывести следующий массив

```
9
6
9
18
9
24
```

```
a = []
n = 30
k=10001
for i in range(0, n):
    a.append(int(input()))
    if a % 6 != 0:
        k=a if a<k else k
for i in range(0, n):
    if a % 6 != 0:
        a=k
print(a)
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 6, in <module>
    if a % 6 != 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Поправил ошибку, именно в 6 строке

Comment: у вас a - list, что вы хотите в этой строке получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = []
n = 30
k=10001
for i in range(0, n):
    x = int(input())
    # добавляем введенное число
    a.append(x)
    # и проверяем его на условие
    if x % 6 != 0:
        k=x if x<k else k

for i in range(0, n):
    # здесь тоже должно быть не имя списка, а его элемент
    if a[i] % 6 != 0:
        a[i]=k
print(a)
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался